# GridView PageIndexChanging Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, page-index-changed

This seems to be an easy question to ask, but I am not able to show items in GridView. Here is my code:

```
 public partial class TestList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {   TestProject.DataAccess.Repository.Instance.Initialize(Settings.Default.TestConnection);
            BindData();
        }

    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        //Restriction Info!!
        gvAgentList.DataSource = EntityRegistration.DataAccess.Repository.Instance.GetData();
        gvAgentList.DataBind();
    }

   protected void gvAgentList_PageIndexChanging (object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

        gvAgentList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gvAgentList.DataBind();
    }

   private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
   {
       string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

       switch (sortDirection)
       {
           case SortDirection.Ascending:
               newSortDirection = "ASC";
               break;

           case SortDirection.Descending:
               newSortDirection = "DESC";
               break;
       }

       return newSortDirection;
   }

   protected void gvAgentList_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
   {
       DataTable dataTable = gvAgentList.DataSource as DataTable;

       if (dataTable != null)
       {
           DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
           dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

           gvAgentList.DataSource = dataView;
           gvAgentList.DataBind();
       }
   }

}
```

Here is the markup of the GridView:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <p>
    Agent Lists:</p>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView runat ="server" ID = "gvAgentList" 
            AllowPaging = "True" 
            AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" AllowSorting="True" BackColor="#E8E8E8" 
            BorderColor="#003399" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Height="375px" 
            Width="731px" OnPageIndexChanging = "gvAgentList_PageIndexChanging" 
            OnSorting="gvAgentList_Sorting" >

        <AlternatingRowStyle ForeColor="#0066CC" />
        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="#3366FF" />

    </asp:GridView>

   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>



    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

The problem is that my GridView is not throwing me any exception and through breakpoints I can see that the function is called in code behind.

> My sorting is also not working :(

Comment: Could you post your mark up code as well? You need to invoke the BindData method in gvAgentList_PageIndexChanging

Comment: @HelloWorld: I called DataBind method in gvAgentList_PageIndexChanging

Comment: What about setting the data source to the grid when page index is changed?

Comment: @HelloWorld: I got what you are saying. Should I go ahead and do it from the UI (GridView) or this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
protected void gvAgentList_PageIndexChanging (object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

        gvAgentList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindData();
    }
```

Comment: If I want to do search in my GridView how should I approach?

Answer (score -3):

Set pageindex property of gridview e.g. PageIndex="10"